# Using SQLCipher encrypted with HTML5 Javascript mobile application

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlcipher

I have used SQLCipher for encrypting my database and put it in assests folder and successfully move it to database directory at run time. I can access encrypted database from Java code, but my application is in HTML5 JavaScript. So my question is `How we can access encrypted database from HTML5 JavaScript.`

Note: I have used JavaScript interface not PhoneGap.

Comment: This would not be possible without native sqlcipher support in the browser.

Comment: @StephenLombardo thanks for your time... any example or tutorial for it ?

Comment: To clarify, I'm saying that I don't think this is possible in standard javascript. Browsers do not bundle SQLCipher, and since you can't modify them it won't work. Cordova is a special case because they link and provide SQLCipher as part of the package.